# Rufus compiling error

Tags: command-line, make, configure, rufus

```
vivek@vivek-N61PB-M2S:/usr/local/src/rufus-1.4.7$ ./configure

checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for rm... /bin/rm
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... no
checking for inline... inline
enabling Large File Support (ISO support)
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/ms-sys/Makefile
config.status: creating src/syslinux/libfat/Makefile
config.status: creating src/syslinux/libinstaller/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libcdio/iso9660/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libcdio/udf/Makefile
config.status: creating src/libcdio/driver/Makefile
config.status: creating res/localization/Makefile





vivek@vivek-N61PB-M2S:/usr/local/src/rufus-1.4.7$ make

Making all in src

make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/rufus-1.4.7/src'

Making all in ms-sys

make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/rufus-1.4.7/src/ms-sys'

  CC     libmssys_a-file.o

In file included from file.c:23:0:
../rufus.h:18:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include <windows.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [libmssys_a-file.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/rufus-1.4.7/src/ms-sys'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/rufus-1.4.7/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Im newb in ubuntu and never compile any apps on ubuntu. I'm following this tutorial [CompilingEasyHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you are trying to compile a cross platform package that is an installer of Linux distributions to a partition or USB drive, when it would be much simpler to install an application that does the same thing as Rufus from the default Ubuntu repositories. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for UNetbootin and install it. 
UNetbootin has been dropped from the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. When I tested the built-in Startup Disk Creator application as a UNetbootin replacement app with a few non-*buntu live .iso images it worked in Ubuntu 18.04 every time.

If you want to install Rufus anyway (because Windows ISOs are supported by Rufus), you should read the README.txt file in the rufus-1.4.7 archive for information about how to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the error:
"In file included from file.c:23:0:
../rufus.h:18:21: fatal error: windows.h: No such file or directory
 #include "

You are missing header files and perhaps much more. This application source and Make files are configured to allow compilation using MinGW under Windows rather than Linux and the program itself will not run directly under Linux.

Given the program you are attempting to compile and your self-professed lack of experience both the previous answer and I are left wondering what your goal is.